# increase the length of layout with increase in size of text(multi-line)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview, android-relativelayout

[image: This is the layout preview i get with the followed code]

I want to increase the height of green line with increase in size of aa length of aa(suppose aa is of multiline around 7 line, then the green line should automatically gets increased), 
i had tried my effort but failed, and now i have no more idea to achieve the above mentioned, following is my xml for the above mentioned layout,

```
//My root layout, which/who contain all the two child layouts(relative and linear layout)
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   //Layout for image and line, here i want to increase the height of "profile_view_line(green line)" with increase in size of text "profile_tv_descriptionName"
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/profile_layout_relDescription">

        //This is the imageview,whose background is tranparent, so if i remove "layout below " property from "profile_view_line", then "profile_view_line" 
        //appear behind imageview(profile_img_description),which must/should not happen, but here i fail as well (as i don't want to appear this behind imageview)
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/profile_img_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/description_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

            //This is the line to be expanded with increase in size of "profile_tv_descriptionName" but with minimum size of 30dp as height 
            //and must grow with the "profile_tv_descriptionName" if (profile_tv_descriptionName) is multi-line

            //i can't set property depending on "profile_tv_descriptionName"
            as it is in another viewgroup(relativeayout), due to which i can't set property on this one
        <View android:layout_below="@id/profile_img_description"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/1dp"
            android:id="@+id/profile_view_line"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/30dp"
            android:background="@color/colorGreen"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
     </RelativeLayout>

     //Layout for description title and description text "aa" which exapnds as expected, here the dependincy is based on above maintained relative layout "profile_layout_relDescription"
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_layout_relDescription"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/profile_layout_relDescription">

        //This is the title, useless in this case but need for appearance
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_tv_description"
            android:text="@string/profile_description"
            android:textSize="@dimen/8dp"
            android:gravity="left"/>

         //this is the dependency factor which can increase and according to which "profile_view_line" green line must expand but i can't do 
         //that because it is in another viewgroup(linearlayout), due to which i can't set property on this one
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/profile_tv_descriptionName"
            android:text="Vikram"
            android:textSize="@dimen/13dp"
            android:gravity="left"/>
      </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout, horizontal>
    <LinearLayout, vertical, width wrap_content, height match_parent, gravity center_horizontal>
        <ImageView set width, set height>
        <View, greeen line, height 0, weight 1>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout, vertical, width 0, height wrap_content, weight 1>
        <TextView title, wrap_content>
        <TextView description, wrap_content>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Explanation:**

You need 4 things in a square:

```
AB
CD
```

where A is the image, B is the title, C is the line, and D is the text.

B and D need to be aligned vertically with each other, and next to A and C, so that says to me that each of those pairs should be in a vertical linear layout, and then those two should be aligned in a horizontal one to line them up.

A and C together have the width that A has, but the other two need to take up the remaining space. That means width of 0, and weight 1.

Now we have:

```
A B----------------------
C D----------------------
```

Now we need to deal with height. A has a fixed height. B and D have a fixed height, defined by the text in them. That leaves C as having a variable height, taking up the rest of the space. So we say that AC has height matching the parent, which is then defined by the height of BD. Then C has a height 0 and weight 1, making it fill all the remaining height. This gives us:

```
A B----------------------
C D----------------------
- -----------------------
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response but i don't see the green line which i have to grow with the description, and i also need the imageview which is not 9patch(simple png)

Comment: @but now that green line view is endliess, which makes other views(not in pic) not to appear in layout

Comment: What height did you give the outer linear layout?

Comment: linearlayout is match parent and is in another layout NestedScrollView(match parent)

Comment: Change the linear layout to wrap_content

Comment: view green line is not appearing as it is wrap content but if i set its minimum height then on expanison of text it didn't expand

Comment: Set it to have height 0 and weight 1

Comment: still green line not appearing

Comment: here is the url of my whole xml code,https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwkVxZWl7VcEeFpnd3JFMnBnMXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have relative layouts instead of linear layouts

Comment: ,for this particular i have used linear layout

Comment: You need to set a specific height for the imageview

Comment: still green color line is not appearing

Comment: The height of the linear layout the line is in needs to be match_parent

Comment: it worked but can u please help me in understanding the concept, how had u managed to do this, i know the concept of weight but unable to understand it

Comment: Sure, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: it works for the longer text but doesnot wrap to some constant height if the there are small no. of text

Comment: set the line minum_height to the smallest you want it

Comment: ,i set the minimum height to green line but still not appearing to some state height and thanks for your expalantion

Comment: this is my updated xml link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwkVxZWl7VcEa1F2OEVzckRIVGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: assist me my friend in setting the minimum height , i am very close to hit otherwise your as well as my effort is waste

Comment: Try setting the linear layout holding the line to have a minimum height of the image + minimum height of the line.